# Excel -- Filter the first row from a list of values; for multiple values?

Tags: excel

All,

I am currently faced with an issue where I need to fetch the first instance of a value in a column, but I have multiple values. No two rows will be the same EXCEPT for the first column.

Example:

```
A  1  !
A  2  @
B  3  #
B  4  $
C  5  %
C  6  ^
D  7  &
D  8  *
```

After filter:

```
A  1  !
B  3  #
C  5  %
D  7  &
```

Would anyone have a way to go about this? Thanks in advanced.

Edit: Jeeped literally pointed something out that I have been doing for a long time, but didn't even think would work in this instance.

To solve this item, utilize the "Remove Duplicates" on the column in question (Column 1), but make sure you expand the selection. However, uncheck all the columns, and recheck only Column 1 for the criteria.

Thanks.

Comment: Data ► Data Tools ► Remove Duplicates.

Comment: Indeed, that is the solution that -- quite oddly -- I wasn't able to reach. Thank you for the simple pointer, I've elaborated upon the suggestion in my original post.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are trying to extract unique values from each column. If so, Excel has a built in function called Advanced Filter, which will do exactly that.

This tutorial will familiarize you with the feature

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Could you show how the 'Unique records only' applies here? Links to sites should only be used to augment your answer; the basics of what you are suggesting should be spelled out.